# Switching environment and extensions from C# to C++ easily

Tags: visual-studio-2010, development-environment

I work on C++ projects, as well as C# projects.

In VS2010, I would like to use window organization and enabled extensions which are specific to the language of the project.

I know I can save the window organization into .vssettings files, and apply the good one when I switch of project.

But is it possible to do so for extensions as well?

And is it possible to associate these settings to a solution file? Or should I create some batch files which would set the settings and enable/disable the extensions, and then load the project?

Thanks in advance

Mike